# D3.js Tooltip not displaying on mouseover (or at all)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I have a map of Kansas City with data for the number of crimes in every neighborhood, and I want to add a tooltip to display the number of crimes in each district when you hover over it. This is where and how I have defined it so far:

```
  var map = d3.select('#map').selectAll('path')
    .data(data[0].features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-width', 0.75)
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        var tooltip = d3.select('#myTooltip');

        tooltip.style('display', 'block');
        tooltip.style('left', d3.event.pageX);
        tooltip.style('top', d3.event.pageY);

        tooltip.html(d.properties.neighbourhood + ': ' + d.count);
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(d) {
        // var tooltip = d3.select('#myTooltip');
        tooltip.style('left', d3.event.pageX);
        tooltip.style('top', d3.event.pageY);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(d) {
        // var tooltip = d3.select('#myTooltip');
        tooltip.style('display', 'none');
    });
```

I also have a separate map.datum where I define the colors. When I load the page, nothing happens at the event, and the web inspector has some weird code under the events.

```
function(i) {
  var o = t.event;
  t.event = i;
  try {
    n.call(this, this.__data__, e, r)
  } finally {
    t.event = o
  }
}
```

Its like that for all three. Has anyone seen this before and have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Appreciate any help or suggestions!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities.  It seems, first, it's not evident where `#myTooltip` is defined in the page.

If it's nested under the `<svg>` it has to be a child of a `<foreignObject>`.  See [MDN foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).  Here's an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411) as well.

If it's outside the svg, it could be that it is hidden by your viz.  Look at the dev tools to see if its attributes change during mouseover as intended.

Comment: I never responded, but the problem was my #myTooltip definition. The css file wasn't linking properly.